# Check all parts windows features are enable and enable off .Net Framework

Tags: c#, powershell

I am using that script to check Windows Feature .Net Framework 4.x is enable

```
    private static bool CheckWindowsFeatureNetFx4()
    {
        try
        {
            Process p = CreateProcess();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName NetFx4";
            p.Start();
            var stand = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            var err = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            var i1 = stand.IndexOf("State");
            var i2 = stand.IndexOf("CustomProperties");
            if (i1 < i2 && (err == null || err == ""))
            {
                var state = stand.Substring(i1 + 19, i2 - i1 - 21);
                Console.WriteLine(state);
                if (state.ToLower() == "enabled")
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return false;
```

And enable this in this way:

```
    private static void RunWindowsFeatureNetFx4(Session session)
    {
        Process p = CreateProcess();
        try
        {
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "Install-WindowsFeature .NET-Framework-45-Features";
            p.Start();
            p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            CheckWindowsFeatureNetFx4(session);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            session["TurnOnWindowsFeature4"] = "false";
        }
    }
```

Problem is it dont check "subfeatures" and only main funkcion is enable return true. I was trying use this RunWindowsFeatureNetFx4 method when not all parts are enable and it does not enable the rest of the features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:
I created Dictionary with all features name which are enabled with .Net Framework 3.5 and 4.x. I took them to compare the return value when features are turned on and off. Next check all enabled and remove it from dictionary. Then enable all functions in the right order. Order is important.

This list work for net framework 4.8

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AddFeature();
        CreateFileFeature();
        RemoveEnable();
        TurnOnFeatures();
    }

    private static void TurnOnFeatures()
    {
        try
        {
            Process p = CreateProcess();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            foreach (var item in featureToEnable)
            {
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:" + item.Value + " /NoRestart";

                p.Start();

                var a = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                var b = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    private static void RemoveEnable()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
        {
            if (featureToEnable.ContainsKey(i))
                if (featureAllEnable.Any(x => x == featureToEnable[i]) == true)
                    featureToEnable.Remove(i);
        }
    }
    private static void AddFeature()
    {
        featureToEnable.Add(0, "NetFx3");
        featureToEnable.Add(1, "NetFx4-AdvSrvs");
        featureToEnable.Add(2, "NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45");
        featureToEnable.Add(3, "WCF-Services45");

        featureToEnable.Add(4, "WCF-TCP-PortSharing45");
        featureToEnable.Add(5, "WCF-Pipe-Activation45");
        featureToEnable.Add(6, "WCF-TCP-Activation45");
        featureToEnable.Add(7, "WCF-MSMQ-Activation45");

        featureToEnable.Add(8, "IIS-NetFxExtensibility");
        featureToEnable.Add(9, "IIS-NetFxExtensibility45");
        featureToEnable.Add(10, "WAS-NetFxEnvironment");
        featureToEnable.Add(11, "IIS-ASPNET45");
        featureToEnable.Add(12, "IIS-ManagementService");
        featureToEnable.Add(13, "IIS-ASPNET");
        featureToEnable.Add(14, "WCF-HTTP-Activation45");
        featureToEnable.Add(15, "WCF-HTTP-Activation");
        featureToEnable.Add(16, "WCF-NonHTTP-Activation");

    }

    private static void CreateFileFeature()
    {
        Process p = CreateProcess();
        try
        {
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C DISM /online /get-features /format:table";
            p.Start();

            var a = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            var b = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            List<string> s = new List<string>();
            int endLine = output.IndexOf("\r\n");
            while (output.Length > 0)
            {
                if (endLine == 0)
                {
                    output = output.Substring(2, output.Length - 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    s.Add(output.Substring(0, endLine));
                    output = output.Substring(endLine, output.Length - endLine);
                }
                endLine = output.IndexOf("\r\n");
            }
            foreach (var item in s)
            {
                if (item.ToLower().Contains("enable"))
                {
                    int ind = item.IndexOf(" ");
                    featureAllEnable.Add(item.Substring(0, ind));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

Edit:

List for net framework 4.7.2. I check framework on pc and use appropriate list

```
        featureToEnable.Add(0, "NetFx3");
        featureToEnable.Add(1, "NetFx3ServerFeatures");
        featureToEnable.Add(2, "NetFx4");
        featureToEnable.Add(3, "NetFx4ServerFeatures");
        featureToEnable.Add(4, "NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45");
        featureToEnable.Add(5, "WAS-NetFxEnvironment");
        featureToEnable.Add(6, "IIS-NetFxExtensibility");
        featureToEnable.Add(7, "IIS-NetFxExtensibility45");
        featureToEnable.Add(8, "IIS-ASPNET45");
        featureToEnable.Add(9, "IIS-ManagementService");
        featureToEnable.Add(10, "WCF-HTTP-Activation45");
        featureToEnable.Add(11, "WCF-TCP-Activation45");
        featureToEnable.Add(12, "WCF-Pipe-Activation45");
        featureToEnable.Add(13, "WCF-MSMQ-Activation45");
        featureToEnable.Add(14, "WCF-HTTP-Activation");
        featureToEnable.Add(15, "WCF-NonHTTP-Activation");
        featureToEnable.Add(16, "WCF-TCP-PortSharing45");
```